# Installing PyQt4 from PyQt4_windows_whl

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I am new to Python and trying to install Spyder for developping scripts.

- I installed Python 2.7, Spyder 3.3.0, and QtPy 1.4.2
- I looked for a PyQty distribution for Windows 32, found this one using pip search

:

```
Name: PyQt4_windows_whl
Version: 4.11.4.1
Summary: Python bindings for the Qt cross platform GUI toolkit
Home-page: https://github.com/takluyver/pyqt4_windows_whl
License: UNKNOWN
Author: Riverbank Computing
```

- I successfully installed the package runing pip wheel and install. Indeed, pip freeze shows me:

  `PyQt4_windows_whl    4.11.4.1`

I also have two new directories:

1. C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4_windows_whl-4.11.4.1.dist-info

=> contains info files METADATA, WHEEL etc.

2. C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4

=> contains Qt.pyd, qmake.exe, lots of dll...

However, when I import QtPy I get this:

```
...
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
```

I also tried these:

import PyQt4

import PyQt

import qt

...
to no avail.

I included the PyQt4 directory into the PATH environment variable.

So my questions are: Is there anything I missed? How can I make Python aware of PyQt4? Does anyone have experience with this PyQt4_windows_whl by Riverbank?

Thank you for your help.